# same iOS app with different personalization?

Tags: ios

I'd like to program an app which essentially has the same functionality, but with different personalization at the icon level.  For instance, the app essentially would have information and communication functionality for a particular business, but I'd like to have the icon/name in front reflect the specific business name.  So in other words, the app would let you do things like browse merchandise and place orders, but for two different clients one would say "Home Depot" and the other would be "Loews" in the icon/name.

In the end, I'm customizing the "storefront" to the client, but the backend is pretty much the same in terms of functionality.

Is there any way to do this programatically? I suppose I could submit different apps to Apple, but given that the code would be essentially the same, wouldn't it get rejected for similar functionality?

Comment: judging by the thousand flashlight apps I don't think there is a similar functionality restriction

Comment: Does the app content change as well? I mean, if one application browses Home Depot merchandise and the other browses Lowes merchandise, those are two completely different things. Shouldn't be an issue, in my mind.

Comment: You are correct, but I would be submitting essentially the same code, with slightly different settings individualized to the specific client.  Doesn't that trigger a red flag? Sorry, my experience in app submission is limited.

Comment: whitelabelling apps is pretty common. as long as you have a different bundle id, icon and name it would be fine